# What is the app-prefs/prefs: link to open another app's settings?

Tags: ios

If this isn't possible it is fine. I was just wondering if it was possible to open an app-prefs or prefs: link to another app's Settings menu. Thanks!

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, as @rmaddy said in the comments.